# Pic^0 of the surface of bitangents of a quartic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Let $S$ be a generic quartic surface in $\mathbf{P}^3$. 
Let $T$ be the surface of the lines bitangent to $S$.

What can we say about $Pic^0(T)$?

Comment: By a theorem of Welters, $h^{1,0}=0$, so it should be zero..

Comment: It is indeed zero. This is Corollary 3.44 in Welters' thesis: *Abel-Jacobi Isogenies for Certain Types of Fano Threefolds*, Math. Centrum, Amsterdam (1981).